Ubuntu 24.03 LTS cannot SSH to over VPN after Docker install
We installed Ubuntu on a new machine and enabled SSH.  Our developers could access this machine over our VPN.  They installed Docker and now we cannot connect to the machine or ping it over VPN.  However internally both SSH and ECHO work fine.  The only change I am aware of is the installation of Docker.  I used UFW to open SSH on the machine (although it again was still working internally) and still does not work over our VPN.  All I can think is docker doesn't like the gateway for some reason, but the machines internal IP is DHCP reservation, so all IP/DNS/Gateway are preconfigured.  I am stumped as top why installing Docker would not only prevent SSH but also disable echo over the vpn.
Thanks in advance for assistance.

Can you ping the computer's local IP address from outside your network using VPN? Did your developers install any containers inside Docker? Which ports do these containers use? What kind of VPN, Wireguard, or openvpn? Edit your question and add all these information inside your question above.

Please check and correct your details; there was no release of Ubuntu in 2024-March (24.03), so your details are incorrect due to typo? or just wrong?
